# Restore Python 2.7 on Monterey 12.3?

Tags: python, monterey

The Monterey 12.3 upgrade removes [Python 2.7](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes#Python) with no user warnings. Homebrew only knows about Python 3. What other ways are there to get Python 2 back up and running?

I'm not interested in hearing arguments about deprecation. We're not a dev shop, just a small mail order business with some internal scripts that need to work again.

Comment: Just remember to ensure that all your scripts use `#! /usr/bin/env python` not `#! /usr/bin/python`. TBH if you just make sure that print statements have brackets and unicode strings are handled correctly, your scripts should work in python3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513250/786389

Comment: @benwiggy - they didn't. Scripts were querying a SQLite database: returned as strings in Python 2, not in 3. Also, the database had '-' for missing numeric values, which Python 2 is fine comparing with a number, but 3 throws an exception

Comment: thanks for question and answer, but, honestly, you can't stick to Python 2 indefinitely. The incompatibilities you mention seem easy to solve. There will be others, of course, but still... And SO is here to help!

Comment: believe me, @WalterTross - they're not easy to solve, at least not in the very limited time I have to do so. Since I have the source of Python 2, I do believe I *can* stick with Python 2 indefinitely

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Python Release Python 2.7.18 | Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) download page has a macOS 64-bit installer download that replaces the missing interpreter.

Comment: Yes: that's the easiest and simplest way.

Comment: It's good for me

Comment: Previous versions of MacOS had 2.7 at `/usr/bin/python` and installing it this way puts it at `/usr/local/bin/python` so you either need to make a symlink or potentially update the path in your scripts.

Comment: Adding to what @JoelMellon said: If a script was hard-coding `#!/usr/bin/python`, you should update it to do `#!/usr/bin/env python` (or `#!/usr/bin/env python2` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) instead, [to make it more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709616/whats-the-difference-between-python-shebangs-with-usr-bin-env-rather-than-hard).

Answer (score 4):

MacPorts packages python27.

I also found an [unofficial tap](https://github.com/kamilturek/homebrew-python2), if you must use Homebrew for some reason, in about 10 sec of searching.